# Codeigniter Bootstrap Carousel Not Working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to work with Bootstrap carousel on my site. And I using images with foreach, but now My carousel is not working. Why isn't it working?

Here's my code on view

```
<script src="<?= base_url() ?>/assets/css/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?= base_url() ?>/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
     <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <!-- Indicators -->
          
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>
     
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
              <img src="<?php echo base_url('upload/product/'.$product->image) ?>" alt="Los Angeles">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3><?php echo $product->name ?></h3>
                <p>Rp. <?php echo number_format($product->price, 2,".") ?></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            
        <?php endforeach; ?>

          <!-- Left and right controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
    
    <!-- slider section end -->
    <!-- collection section start -->
```

Can you tell me what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong type to add foreach loop here please a foreach loop inside the carousel-inner class and item active class div add inside this loop  and put some condition for active class and then it should be work definatly.